# Apply 301 redirect in Google App Engine Standard

Tags: nginx, google-app-engine

We need to route all www traffic to non-wwww. so https://www.mywebsite.com should 301 redirect to https://mywebsite.com.

In GAE, you cannot use an `.htaccess` file, so I think the only option is to do this in the Nginx config.

I created a test project to test this.

It's a Hello World app with the following `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php74

runtime_config:
  nginx_conf_include: nginx-app.conf
```

the `nginx-app.conf` file is on the same level as `app.yaml` and has the following contents:

```
# Redirect www to non-www
if ( $host ~ ^www\.(?<domain>.+) ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$domain/$1;
}
```

The documentation states that this file is:
`Filename of a partial nginx config which will be included in the server section in the main nginx config file.`

visiting my project URL with `www` gives an insecure SSL error and does not redirect.

How can I apply a 301 redirect in Google App Engine Standard?

Comment: I would do the redirect in your own code instead of trying to use nginx.  I think you can't use nginx with GAE standard.

Comment: I think you're right. I must have been looking at the flex docs. This is strange. There's really absolutely no way to handle 301 redirects other than doing it in PHP? Why is GAE like this? Makes no sense to me. It's a basic part of managing a site

Answer (score 1):

Like @gaefan mentioned, I think nginx file can not be served by app engine standard.

If you want to serve both domains, in the App Engine Standard environment, the easier way is create a separate service (let's call it `redirect`) and use [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-routed#dispatch) to route all `https://www.mywebsite.com` to `redirect`, and handle redirect requests there.